# why does Jsoup selector div#id work in netbeans but not in eclipse ADT?

Tags: android, eclipse, netbeans, jsoup, adt

Following code works fine in netbeans, but in eclipse ADT, `doc.select("div#tickertape_eng a").size()` returns 0.

```
try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://bdnews24.com").get();
            if (doc != null) {
                Elements links = doc.select("div#tickertape_eng a");
                for (Element link : links) {
                    headlines.add(link.text());
                    headlinks.add(link.absUrl("href"));
                }

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Doc not found",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

In netbeans, I can print link.text() and link.absUrl("href"), but not in eclipse.
Eclipse prints doc.title() in logcat fine, but why does doc.select("div#tickertape_eng a") not work? How to make it work?

Comment: You want text inside of `a` tag & the `url`?

Comment: yes, with div id="tickertape_eng"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://bdnews24.com")
  .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0")
  .get();
```

The user agent is what let the server guess which browser you are using. If it detects a mobile browser, it can redirect you to a mobile page. So forcing a desktop browser user agent is a way to make sure you get the standard page located at bdnews24.com.

You can find most of the available user agents here: http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php

Comment: No, it causes the program to crash. Does it have to do anything with the browser? I'm using google chrome.

Comment: It crashes? That's weird. No, I thought, when you are executing with ADT, that the bdnews24.com website redirects you to the mobile page, bdnews24.com/mobile and so, your parsing was on the wrong page. So my proposition was basically to cheat in order to get the right page.

Comment: It worked! .get() part was missing, that's why it wasn't working. Thank you so much for pointing out the redirecting to the mobile site. I've been working the whole day for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://bdnews24.com").get();
Elements div = doc.select("div#tickertape_eng");

   Elements get = div.select("a[href]");

     for (Element elem : get) {

         System.out.println("Link : " +elem.attr("href"));
         System.out.println("Text  : " +elem.text());        
    }
}
```

**Prints**:

```
Link : http://bdnews24.com/politics/2015/02/18/euro-mps-will-continue-to-urge-bnp-to-sever-ties-with-jamaat-hifazat-says-junior-minister
Text  : Euro MPs will continue to urge BNP to sever ties with Jamaat, Hifazat, says junior minister
Link : http://bdnews24.com/bangladesh/2015/02/18/appellate-division-publishes-full-verdict-on-jamaat-leader-kamaruzzaman
Text  : Appellate Division has published full verdict on Jamaat leader Kamaruzzaman
Link : http://bdnews24.com/bangladesh/2015/02/18/jamaat-e-islami-leader-abdus-subhan-to-hang-for-war-time-atrocities-in-pabna
Text  : Jamaat-e-Islami leader Abdus Subhan to hang for war-time atrocities in Pabna
Link : http://bdnews24.com/bangladesh/2015/02/18/prosecution-happy-with-subhan-verdict-defence-says-will-appeal
Text  : Prosecution happy with Subhan verdict, defence says will appeal
Link : http://bdnews24.com/bangladesh/2015/02/18/un-chief-writes-to-hasina-khaleda-urges-for-talks
Text  : UN Secy-Gen Ban Ki-moon writes to Hasina, Khaleda, urges for talks
```